# Implement Future.sequence for case class CanBuildFrom Traversable Iterator Sequence Monad

Tags: scala, scalability, scalaz

I have this:

```
case class Sides[A](east: A, west: A)
```

I want to convert this `Sides[Future[Boolean]]` into this `Future[Sides[Boolean]]`

using `Future.sequence` how?

This is the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$):

```
def
sequence[A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[Future[A]])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[A]], A, M[A]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[A]]
 Permalink
Simple version of Future.traverse. Transforms a TraversableOnce[Future[A]] into a Future[TraversableOnce[A]]. Useful for reducing many Futures into a single Future
```

Comment: You need to implement `Traverse[Sides]`. It will not be `Future.sequence` (there is no such thing, without running the Future), but `Sides.sequence`.

Comment: If you read the definition of `sequence` you'll see


```def sequence[A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[Future[A]])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[A]], A, M[A]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[A]]```



So your `Sides` needs to be a subclass of `TraversableOnce`.

Comment: @mfirry can you implement that please, I can't do `CanBuildFrom` thing.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Future.sequence`? If you are using `scala.concurrent.Future` won't something like this work: `def sequenceSides[A](sides: Sides[Future[A]])(implicit exec: ExecutionContext): Future[Sides[A]] =
    for { east <- sides.east; west <- sides.west } yield Sides(east, west)` ?

Comment: @Kolmar I have north south too and I want neat code.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Since this question has the `scalaz` tag, I was assuming that the `Future` in question was from `scalaz`. After the question has been edited, it is clear that the OP has `Future` from Scala standard library in mind.

---

I am expanding my comment as an answer. You need a `Traverse` instance for `Sides`, not `Future`. (There exists no `Traverse` instance for `Future`, unless you are willing to eagerly evaluate the `Future`.)

```
import scalaz.{Applicative, Traverse}
import scalaz.concurrent.Future
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

case class Sides[A](east: A, west: A)

implicit def traverseSides: Traverse[Sides] = new Traverse[Sides] {
  def traverseImpl[G[_], A, B](s: Sides[A])(f: A => G[B])(implicit G: Applicative[G]): G[Sides[B]] =
    G.apply2(f(s.east), f(s.west))(Sides(_, _))
}

val sf: Sides[Future[Boolean]] = ???
vaf fs: Future[Sides[Boolean]] = sf.sequence
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but, `Future sequence` doesn't eagerly evaluate I think that's what I want.

Comment: @user3995789 There has been a misunderstanding about which Future we were talking about. `Future.sequence[A, M[_]]` from stdlib uses the traversable structure of `M`, not `Future`, so it is consistent with what I said - that `Future` cannot be traversable unless you force it to evaluate.